# calculating distance between two points in python class

Tags: python, python-class

I am trying to calculate the distance between 2 points in python using this code :

```
import math
class Point(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point({0}, {1})".format(self.x, self.y)
    def __sub__(self, other):
        return Point(self.x - other.x, self.y - other.y) #<-- MODIFIED THIS
    
    def distance(self, other):
        p1 = __sub__(Point(self.x , other.x))**2
        p2 = __sub__(Point(self.y,other.y))**2
        p = math.sqrt(p1,p2)
        return p


def dist_result(points):
    points = [Point(*point) for point in points]
    return [points[0].distance(point) for point in points]
```

but it is returning:

```
NameError: name '__sub__' is not defined
```

can you please show me how to correctly write that function ?

so I am expecting an input of:

```
1=(1,1)  and  2=(2,2)
```

and I would like to calculate the distance using:

```
=|2−1|=(1−2)^2+(1−2)^2
```

Comment: Please provide input/ouput example of twhat you expect

Comment: @azro done! i edited it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only formula you need is the Pythagorean theorem, and you don't need to create some temporary point, just do:

```
def distance(self, other):
    dx = (self.x - other.x) ** 2
    dy = (self.y - other.y) ** 2
    return math.sqrt(dx + dy)
```

---

The `__sub__` is to override the minus `-` operator, between `Point` instances

Answer (score 1):

`__sub__` is an instance method, not a global function.  The general way you call an instance method is as an attribute on the instance, e.g.:

```
difference = p1.__sub__(p2)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
difference = Point.__sub__(p1, p2)
```

Since `__sub__` is a magic method, you can also invoke it via the subtraction operator:

```
difference = p1 - p2
```

To implement your `distance` method in terms of your `__sub__` method I think you want something along the lines of:

```
    def distance(self, other):
        diff = self - other
        return math.sqrt(diff.x ** 2 + diff.y ** 2)
```